# Using regex capture group in nginx $args

Tags: regex, nginx

As some background, I'm trying to fix requests that are coming in with duplicated params e.g:

```
/products/compare/?ids=554?ids=554
/products/compare/?ids=595,662,726?ids=595,662,726
```

My fix - which works - looks like this:

```
location /products/compare/ {
    if ( $args ~ "(ids=[\d,]+)\?ids=[\d,]+" ) {
        set $id $1;
        rewrite ^.*$ $scheme://$host/$uri$is_args$id? permanent;
    }
}
```

My question is regarding the `set $id $1;`, and why it's necessary

I *was* using the `$1` capture-group variable directly in the rewrite:

```
rewrite ^.*$ $scheme://$host/$uri$is_args$1? permanent;
```

But the variable wasn't being populated.

Why not?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you use the set command, the variable does populate? btw, nice name :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first parameter of the `rewrite` directive is a regular expression which may contain numbered captures. As a result, all numbered captures are reset when the `rewrite` statement is entered.

As an alternative to using the `set` directive, you could use a named capture within your `if` statement's regular expression.

For example:

```
if ( $args ~ "(?<id>ids=[\d,]+)\?ids=[\d,]+" ) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/$uri$is_args$id? permanent;
}
```

---

Of course, you do not actually need to use `rewrite`. If you use `return` instead, the numeric capture remains in scope.

For example:

```
if ( $args ~ "(ids=[\d,]+)\?ids=[\d,]+" ) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/$uri$is_args$id;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. And yes, good point about `return` rather than `rewrite`.